# Create a csv or simple text file using only streams

Tags: java, csv, inputstream

I'm about to use a jsf Primefaces download button to download a csv file.
The file doesn't exists and it can't use the Export utility because I need to build the csv at runtime.

This is a test attempt which works:

```
    private StreamedContent file;

    /** Getter,setter...*/
    public void FileDownloadBean() {
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.csv");
          file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/csv", "test.csv"); 
    }
```

The fact I'm using Primefaces doesn't really count here, what I want to achieve is to build a file of any kind, preferably CSV, without actually saving a (temp) file in the file-system.

I would like to append my data using a stream, so then I can easily append and manipulate `String`s, `byte`s, and `image` files.

Any ideas? Maybe a Stringbuffer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Down-voters are welcome to state their reasons. This seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can *"create a file without creating a file"*.

Use a `String`, `StringBuffer`, `StringBuilder`, or other ***variable*** to have the file's ***contents*** in memory.

***Edit:*** Apparently, there are also streams to memory (?): `ByteArrayInputStream` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, the following answer "maybe" solves your problem:

```
public class InMemoryStreaming {
private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

public void FileDownloadBean() throws IOException {
    InputStream csvStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.csv");
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            csvStream))) {
        // on every method call the StringBuilder is appended
        sb.append(br.lines().collect(
                Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to serialize the `StringBuilder` into a real File, you can do it with the appropriate writer.